# How to backfill column in Postgres without locking the table?

Tags: postgresql, bulkupdate

I recently added a new column to my 40+ million row Postgres table (v9.6) with

```
ALTER TABLE queries
   ADD COLUMN ml_partition_source UUID;
```

Then in another transaction I executed

```
ALTER TABLE queries
   ALTER COLUMN ml_partition_source
      SET DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid();
```

I did this in two transactions, because setting a `default` on a new column causes Postgres to rewrite the whole table, which can take hours and isn't acceptable in production.

Now, I'd like to backfill this column for all of the `query`s which existed before the new column was added without locking the table. One way to do this would be through a CRUD API I have but some rough calculations show that this would take ~22 days (maybe my API performance can be improved but that's a whole different question). Instead, I tried writing a postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION backfill_partition_source()
  RETURNS void AS $$
declare
  query_ record;
BEGIN
  for query_ in
  select * from api_mldata.queries where ml_partition_source is null
  loop
    update api_mldata.queries SET ml_partition_source = public.gen_random_uuid() where id = query_.id;
  end loop;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and executed that with `select backfill_partition_source();`. But that ended up locking the table too.

How can I backfill a column without impacting production (or with minimal production impact)?

EDIT: one idea I have is "chunking" the Postgres script to operate on 100k rows at a time or something like that and then executing the script in a loop. So the select statement would become

```
select * from api_mldata.queries
where ml_partition_source is null
limit 100000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get away without locking at all, but you can keep the locks reasonably short.

Rather than running many single-row updates in a loop, run bigger updates:

```
UPDATE api_mldata.queries
SET ml_partition_source = DEFAULT
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 999999;
```

Here `id` is the primary key of the table.

That way you can be done with a few bigger updates, each for a different range of `id`s.

To avoid bloat and excessive locking, run each statement in its own transaction and launch an explicit `VACUUM` on the table between statements.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! Do you anticipate any problems if the primary key of the table is a UUID?

Comment: No, that should work fine. You also don't have to use the primary key - any column that can be used to create reasonable chunks efficiently is fine.